# Why does this not return the correct divisors?

Tags: python, list, modulo

I'm very new to Python and coding in general. I learned a bit of Python 2 because it was the best available version for free :)
Below is the code I wrote:

```
num = int(input("What number would you like to check the divisors of? "))
Divisors = list(range(1, num+1))
for element in Divisors:
    if num % element != 0:
        Divisors.remove(element)
print(Divisors)
```

This is what it prints out:

```
What number would you like to check the divisors of? 12
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: Mutating a list while iterating over it is bug-prone. In any event -- why do this at all? Why not build up the list of divisors directly rather than remove non-divisors? Your current logic is convoluted. When you start with e.g. `1,000,000` your approach will create a list of 1 million numbers just to throw most of them away. It is also painfully slow. Your code will hang if fed `10,000,000,000`, but a more efficient implementation will be able to handle that number in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Tangentially -- Python 3 is also free, and it makes a lot more sense to be learning it since Python 2 has reached the end of its life and is no longer being actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you're modifying the list Divisors as you iterate over it.
It makes your code skip some elements in the array, try printing the current element like this:

```
num = int(input("What number would you like to check the divisors of? "))
Divisors = list(range(1, num+1))
for element in Divisors:
    print("The current element is", element)
    if num % element != 0:
        Divisors.remove(element)
```

To understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Divisors inside an iteration is going to have side effects.  Instead you can use list comp to get what you want.

```
num = int(input("What number would you like to check the divisors of? "))
Divisors = list(range(1, num+1))
Divisors = [ element for element in Divisors if num % element == 0 ]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```